# Can a lightbulb once inserted into your mouth be safely removed?

Tags: physiology, dentistry, light

There is a viral video going around that [repeats a claim I've heard before about getting a light bulb stuck in your mouth](https://www.facebook.com/8dank/videos/1807145086270035/)

[image: The bulb shape allows it to be put into the mouth, but taking it out is problematic.]

Graphic reads,

> The bulb shape allows it to be put into the mouth, but taking it out is problematic.

Central to the claim seems to be the jaw muscles clenching up. Is there any actual work debunking this claim. I've always wanted to put a light bulb in my mouth and I'm wondering if it is a bad idea.

Comment: Note the end of the video: Avoid experimenting! I would recommend you don't stick things that aren't meant to go in your mouth into your mouth. :)

Comment: The first issue is there are many sizes for lightbulbs.

Comment: I don't suppose a [magic act](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ethCJ4bfJkg) counts as evidence, but it does highlight the question of sizes.

Comment: @Oddthinking The A19 is the most common bulb, but I don't think the average person can even get it in their mouth in the first place. [Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnUNt.png) The picture appears to be one from the A series.

Comment: [The A19 is 60mm or 2.375 inches wide at it's widest point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-series_light_bulb).

Comment: *"Most studies show that the maximum jaw range of motion (ROM) or maximum mouth opening (MMO) is related to body size and height. So men can usually open wider than women, taller people more than shorter people. In studies, MMO for adults has generally been around 50 mm, with a range from 32mm to 77mm."* [Source](http://www.craniorehab.com/What-is-the-average-jaw-mouth-opening-_b_3.html). I know original research is not allowed, but I'd say a large chunk of people can't even fit the bulb in their mouth in the first place.

Comment: Note that "taking it out is problematic" doesn't mean "taking it out is impossible". The shape of the bulb means that pulling it out will put a lot of stress on the neck, because if you don't open your mouth wide enough before, it'll drag on your lips and teeth, and if that breaks, it'll shatter in your mouth -- compare that to what happens if it breaks on the way in.

Comment: I'm going to guess that, for the purpose of this claim, they mean "a lightbulb shaped just large enough that the person can barely get it into their mouth".

Comment: YouTube has a bunch of videos called "one-minute challenge", "#uvula", and stuff like that, where people try to keep their mouths open for a long period of time.  Apparently it's a challenge because the muscles can get tired and it becomes difficult for them to keep their mouths open.  There's a NSFW-aspect to it.

Answer (score 16):

While it's a bad idea to put fragile glass objects in your mouth, the primary assertion here is clearly false.

First of all, there are at least five different YouTube videos where people try it out and have no problems. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPPEPqwIvgU) is one that includes various sizes and shapes.

Secondly, if this were possible, it is likely that cases would appear in the medical literature, but they don't. It is not difficult to find documented cases of [light bulbs stuck in people's rectums](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/13179360), of [children swallowing small LEDs](http://www.livescience.com/52151-led-light-bulb-toddler-cough.html) and so on. [Here](http://www.hospital-data.com/accidents/627-light-bulbs/mouth/index.html) is a dataset of nearly 2000 light-bulb related mouth injuries presented at hospitals. While only some descriptions are available and all of them are brief, they are just burns, cuts and the like. None of the available descriptions mention one getting "stuck".

EDIT: To be clear, cuts from light bulbs in the mouth don't necesserily imply that the bulb was stuck. Here are typical descriptions of the injuries.

- 2 [year old male] BIT A LIGHT BULB AT HOME. PATENTS GOT SOME PIECES FROM
  MOUTH. DX-ABRASIONS MOUTH.
- 19 [month old male] BIT LIGHT BULB IT BROKE, HIT MOUTH. DX MOUTH CONTUSION
- 2 [year old male] PLAYING W/ A LIGHT BULB WHEN HE PLACED IT IN MOUTH, LIGHT BULB BROKE. GLASS CUT PTS LIPS. DX MOUTH LAC

Comment: I briefly search for medical literature about light bulbs stuck in the mouth as well and could not find anything. Also light bulbs stuck in the rectum I did find.

Comment: Cuts to the mouth from a lightbulb might mean one was stuck at some point.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt Not necessarily... I'll edit to add some sample descriptions.

Comment: It looks like 2/3 were toddlers and a significant portion involved falling while changing a bulb. I still hold out that some of the ones with no note could be getting stuck.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt That's pure speculation unless you can find an explicit case.

Comment: Old saying: Clever men learn from their mistakes. Wise men learn from other people's mistakes.